# iPhone OS: EXC_BAD_ACCESS and xcode freezing while debugging on device?

Tags: xcode, ios

So usually when EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens when I'm debugging my (largely c++ based) iphone app, I can go over to the GDB window and it'll show me the current stack.

However, for some reason, lately XCode freezes. This happened on both xcode 4 and xcode 3.

By freezing, I mean the wheel of death just spins non-stop, and after a while, the whole OS becomes unresponsive. On many occassions, I had to turn off the mac manually.

Could this be a case of trashing? I'm compiling a 300 files, 150k sloc project on an old 2009 mac mini with only 1GB memory. Could this be the reason? I'm pretty close to just buying a new mac mini with 8GB memory, but it seems a bit unlikely that a 2 year old computer can't handle simple compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering I use 2GB of RAM without even loading Xcode, your 1GB could well be a problem.

It also could be a recursive bug that causes the debugger a hell of a lot of work by having an enormous stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an problem in some infinite while/for loop. Try to set break-point in all such kind of piece of code where while/for loop are used.